# Image inside text that doesn't overlay with CSS

Tags: css, responsive-design

I need to put an image inside a text but the image shouldn't go over the text.

This is what i'm trying to achieve:

[image]

This is the HTML structure I've used:

```
    <div class="fascia__desc">
        <img src="img/tmp/test.png" alt="">
        <p>Quisque posuere tempus varius. Mauris eros tortor, sollicitudin non sem id, volutpat fermentum diam. Fusce tempor elit ac pretium pulvinar. Donec lacinia, lacus vel tempus porta, metus velit elementum risus</p>
    </div>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
.fascia__desc img{position: absolute; left: 33.5%; top: 30%;}
.fascia__desc { padding:50px 0; position:relative; }
.fascia__desc p { max-width:610px; margin:0 auto; text-color:#000000; text-align:center; }
```

But since the site should be responsive when I resize the window the image moves above the text and that's not what I want. Can someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: CSS Isn't quite there yet to wrap around irregular shapes...you need to look into [**CSS Shapes**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-shapes-1/) although some browsers are now (experimatally) supporting it. - http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-shapes

Answer (score 0):

> css:

```
  .fascia__desc img{position: relative;margin:5px;float:left}
    .fascia__desc { padding:50px 0; position:relative; }
    .fascia__desc p { max-width:610px; margin:0 auto; text-color:#000000; text-align:justify; }
```

> HTML:

```
<div class="fascia__desc">
      <p>
         Quisque posuere tempus varius. Mauris eros tortor, sollicitudin non sem     id, volutpat fermentum diam.

    <img src="paper.gif" alt="">

      Fusce tempor elit ac pretium pulvinar. Donec lacinia, lacus vel tempus    porta, metus velit elementum risus
      Fusce tempor elit ac pretium pulvinar. Donec lacinia, lacus vel tempus porta, metus velit elementum risus
      </p>
</div>
```